# Receiving files python socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I was trying to create a python socket server that could send and receive data, so I created a socket on the server using the code here:

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 1208))
serversocket.listen(5)
(client,(ip,port)) = serversocket.accept()
```

Then I tried to create a sample connection from my machine by going to command prompt and typing

```
telnet www.filesendr.com 1208
```

However, the console simply replies with "Could not open connection to the host, on port 1208...Connection failed." I went back over my code but couldn't identify the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know how `telnet` works right? First get an understanding, learn about the ways to use it.

Comment: Try this `man telnet`, get an understanding of how it works, and then edit your question.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I tried `man telnet` but it didn't recognize it as a command and I couldn't find anything when I googled it.

Comment: @drfiz98 Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: Are you using the IP given to you by the router, or one you just came up with on the spot?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that after you accept the connection you don't do anything else.  Once the accept happens, you get to the end of the script, python exits and closes all open file handles (including the socket you just opened).  If you want to be able to talk to yourself through telnet, try something like this:

```
import socket
import select
import sys

port = 1208
listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
listener.bind(('',port))
listener.listen(128)
newSock, addr = listener.accept()
while True:
    r,w,e = select.select([newSock,sys.stdin],[],[])
    if newSock in r:
        data = newSock.recv(4096)
        sys.stdout.write(data)
    if sys.stdin in r:
        newSock.send(sys.stdin.readline())
```